# .NET MVC website into Chrome App

Tags: java, serial-port, google-chrome-app

at my job we are developing a MVC .NET website, which use RXTX Java library for serial communication, it's really simple, just sending strings to serial port, but i really want to part away with java and i thinks that a chrome app could solve our problems.

My question is, how can i have a chrome app that shows our website, and how can our website use the serial api from the chrome app. It's that possible? What other possibilities do i have?

I know that i could use a service for communicate with the serial port too, but i like the idea of having a website that runs just like a native app, but, is a good idea?

Comment: Your server is running a .net website, which uses a Java serial library?

Comment: That's right. The website runs an applet that calls the serial library in the client.

Answer (score 0):

There is the USB api, perhaps you can find a USB-to-serial adapter and write a module using chrome.usb

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question.

You can write a packaged app which communicates with the *clients* serial port.

A description can be found here: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial.html

Once you receive data on the client, you can push it back to the *server*.

Comment: OK, I already know that. My question is, how can I show my website in the chrome app? Like a frame.

Comment: Well, you have to write the app, which is HTML, JS and CSS in a package. Inside of this app you can communicate with your server. It's also possible to host your website inside of a webview, but then you have the problem to inject your serial data into the webview.